# Setting Img src attribute in Angular produces error

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files" class="record-row">
    <div class="colCell fileAttributes">
        <div ng-if="!(file.thumbnail === '')" class="collCell-container thumbnail-container">
            <img class="" ng-src="{{ file.thumbnail }}" />
        </div>
        <div class="collCell-container name-container">
            <a class="name-container--filename">
                <span ng-click="getFile(file.id,file.extension,file.fileName)">{{ file.fileName }}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="name-container--fileweight">
                <span>{{ file.fileSizeByte }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular Version is 1.3.14. The Code worked fine (functions worked and all outputs) until I added `ng-src="{{ file.thumbnail }}"`.
This gives me the error `Unknown provider: urlattrFilterProvider <- urlattrFilter`
. Even outputting  `{{ file.thumbnail }}` as text outside of the attribute works fine.
Is this way not correct for setting the src of an image?

Answer (score 0):

Just use src="{{file.thumbnail}}"
instead of ng-src="{{file.thumbnail}}"

Comment: this produces the same error

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer but might be helpful:
the `Unknown provider:...` error usually shows up when we are injecting something to an angular module the wrong way, eiher a mispelled dependency or a dependency injected in the wrong order.
Make sure the error is coming where you're expecting it from, you can just set a breakpoint on exceptions and confirm this.